# Dynamic value lookup if input is between two set values

Tags: excel-formula

A table contains a list of number and a list of starting values for when the numbers are valid. A separate table has a list of inputs for which the output must be calculated.

Calculation rules:

- If the input is greater than or equal to the lower of two sequential start values and less than the higher of the same two start values, the number corresponding with the lower start value is valid.
- If the input is lower than the first start value, the output is 0.
- If the input is greater than or equal to the highest start value, the output is the number corresponding to the highest start value.
- The values in the Number and Start fields are dynamic. In other words, the values can't be hard coded.
- Start values will always be in ascending order.

For example:

[image: Example Tables]

The following formula works, but I'm trying to increase my Excel skills by considering options which would shorten the overall number of characters. I suppose it's a little bit of a Code Golf situation.

```
=IF(D2<B$2, 0,
   IF(D2<=B$3, A$2,
     IF(D2<=B$4, A$3,
       IF(D2<=B$5, A$4,
         IF(D2<=B$6, A$5, A$6)
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

My current solution doesn't scale well because of the nature of embedded if statements. The goal is to reduce the number of characters necessary to compute the right output values with no concern for readability. It's okay to create reference cells if necessary, but I've been trying to avoid that.

This a dive into nitty-gritty algorithms more than anything else. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more succinct and readable answer after considerable trial and error. Unfortunately, I had to add another field (`Stop`), but the resulting formula is much more readable and idiomatic. See below.

[image]

This is the formula in F2: `=SUM(J4>=C$11:C$15*(J4<E$11:E$15)*F$11:F$15)`